# UnicodeDecodeError after upgrading to django-rest-framework 3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Under django-rest-framework 2, the following works fine:

```
from rest_framework import rest_response, generics
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer

class SomeView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    renderer_classes = JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... 
        # Build a response dict with non-ascii in it
        ...
        return rest_response.Response(some_dict_with_non_ascii_in_it_somewhere)
```

I didn't have to explicitly encode any non-ascii...

However, after upgrading to DRF 3, the same code now throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 119, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 261, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 5, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 164, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 158, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 71, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
  File "/Users/troy/.virtualenvs/publisher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 104, in render
    separators=separators
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 210, in encode
    return ''.join(chunks)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 671: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm guessing DRF 3 now has some new config value, somewhere, that was default under DRF 2.  I've tried setting the REST_FRAMEWORK `UNICODE_JSON` setting to `True`, but I still get the same error...

Is there a setting that can make that piece behave as DRF 2 did? or does DRF 3 need me to hunt down the non-ascii character in my dictionary and manually encode it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer.

In DRF 2, `rest_framework.JSONRenderer.ensure_ascii` is set to `True`.  In DRF 3, `rest_framework.JSONRenderer.ensure_ascii` is set to `not api_settings.UNICODE_JSON` (I had missed the `not` there earlier, when I wrote the question...).

So to get it to behave like DRF 2, I needed to set the 'UNICODE_JSON' to `False` instead of `True`, like I had tried before (it is True by default):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'UNICODE_JSON': False
}
```

Alternatively, I could, of course, encode my dictionary values, which in many cases could be the better option.

Answer (score 3):

By default Python 2.7 consider strings are binary.
Try adding at the top of your files:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

That will make your strings unicode by default and should help get them converted correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try, and while it did make it so all of the relevant strings are now unicode within the dict, the library code that processes the Response object and transforms the dict to a string doesn't have that import statement, so stuff gets converted back to a mixture of unicode & regular strings before it does the `''.join()`...